# Set ManyToMany field in model save method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem, I try to save the model and only adds to 'members' the users that belong to the company set in the field 'company'.

This is my code:

```
class GroupFolderAccess(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='belongs')
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='folders')
    folder = models.ForeignKey('recourse.Folder', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='get_group')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for member in self.members.all():
            if self.company != member.company:
                print(member)
                self.members.remove(member)

        return super(GroupFolderAccess, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I save, it displays users correctly, but does not remove them from the relationship.

Comment: does the `print(?)` function working?

Comment: Yes, it print the users I want to remove from the relationship, but nothing happens after saving.

Comment: Does the removing process happen through Django Shell?

Comment: It never happens, it is saved normally and in the shell it prints the users that should be deleted but it does not delete them.

Comment: Maybe try calling super(...) first and then remove them?

Comment: This doesn't work either:
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupFolderAccess, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        rm_members = []
        for member in self.members.all():
            if self.company != member.company:
                print(member)
                rm_members.append(member)
        self.members.set(member)`